# vpn through google cloud gce

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to setup a small GCE to use as a VPN gateway when I travel.  My current attempt is to setup OpenVPN on Ubuntu 16.04 using the script at `https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-linux-14-04-or-16-04-lts/`.  I was able to run the script and get an `ovpn` file at the end.  On my laptop (Kubuntu 16.04) I was able to connect to the GCE machine using network manager by importing the `ovpn` file.

On my laptop I can see the connection is successful but I am not getting any data through the connection (ie I can't go to any websites in my browser).

What I am not sure is if I need to make changes to the Google Network Firewall based on the comments in the link:

```
#OpenVPN Forward by vg
-A ufw-before-forward -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
#OpenVPN END by vg
```

So, if something like that is needed, how do I setup the commands in the Google Network Firewall?

I do have the 1194 port pointing to my GCE instance which is why I assume I am able to see the VPN connect.

Comment: On my local machine I am able to ping 10.8.0.1 which is the IP of the GCE machine (tun0).  So, it is making a connection through to GCE.  It just seems that data going out of GCE to the world isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a quick test in my own project, and it works fine.

In my case I don't have any firewall rule, running in the openvpn-server.

Keep in mind that you need to configure your internal ip as IP listening and set the public IP when the program asks you.

In your example they use the same IP.

Also I have set a rule Firewall rule in the Google Cloud project allowing the inbound traffic for the port 1194